Calculating the Expected Hitting Time on an undirected graph.
I have the following undirected graph:

where $K_{n-1}$ is a complete graph with $n-1$ nodes and $v$ is connected to a node $u \in K_{n-1}$. I am trying to set up a formula to calculate the exact value of $h_{u,v}$, the expected number of steps from $u$ to $v$.
This is my approach so far:
$$h_{u,v} = 1+ \frac{1}{n-1} \cdot h_{v,v} + \frac{1}{n-1} \cdot \sum_{i\neq u,i \neq v}{h_{i,v}}$$
$$h_{i,v} = 1 + \frac{1}{n-2} \cdot h_{u,v} + \frac{1}{n-2}\cdot (n-3) \cdot h_{i,v} \text{  (due to symmetry)} \iff$$
$$h_{i,v} = n - 2 + h_{u,v}$$
The graph is complete and adding the single edge between $u$ and $v$ gives $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}+1$ edges. Thus $h_{v,v} = \frac{2|E|}{dv} = n^2 - 3 n + 4$
Which gives me $$h_{u,v} = 1+ \frac{1}{n-1} \cdot (n^2 - 3 n + 4) + \frac{1}{n-1} \cdot (n - 2 + h_{u,v}) \cdot (n-2)$$
Solving for $h_{u,v}$ results in $h_{u,v} = 2 n^2 - 6 n + 7$, which I know is wrong but I don't really see what went wrong here.

Looks like you can model this as a 3-state discrete time Markov chain $0, 1, 2$ with $P_{00}=(n-3)/(n-2)$, $P_{01}=1/(n-2)$, $P_{12}=1/(n-1)$, $P_{10}=(n-2)/(n-1)$.

If you're at some vertex of $K_{n-1}\backslash{\{u\}}$, then at each step you have a probability of $\frac{1}{n-2}$ of getting to $u$. So, the expected number of steps to get from $K_{n-1}\backslash{\{u\}}$ to $u$ is $n-2$. Then:
$$h_{uv}=\frac{1}{n-1}\cdot 1+\frac{n-2}{n-1}(1+(n-2)+h_{uv})$$
Multiplying by $(n-1)$ and collecting the $h_{uv}$ terms gives
$$h_{uv}=1+(n-2)(n-1)=n^2-3n+3$$

Following Michael's idea, group all the states of $K_{n-1}\setminus\{u\}$ in a unique state $w$. Your Markov chain is still well defined on $\{u,v,w\}$ (because all the states grouped in $w$ played the same part in the initial graph). The transition matrix is
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \frac{1}{n-1} & \frac{n-2}{n-1} \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\frac{1}{n-1}&0 & \frac{n-2}{n-1}
\end{array}\right)$$
Thanks to first step analysis (conditioning on the value of the first step), one can show that
$$h_{u,v}=1+\frac{n-2}{n-1}h_{w,v}\text{ and }h_{w,v}=1+\frac{1}{n-1}h_{u,v}+\frac{n-2}{n-1}h_{w,v}$$
You get a linear system
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} n-1& 2-n\\ -1 & 1 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} h_{u,v} \\ h_{w,v}\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} n-1\\ n-1\end{array}\right)$$
whose unique solution is
$$\left(\begin{array}{c} h_{u,v}\\h_{w,v} \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1& n-2\\ 1 & n-1 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} n-1\\ n-1 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} (n-1)^2\\n(n-1) \end{array}\right)$$
By the way, you found $h_{w,v}=n(n-1)$ which is the expected time to reach $v$ starting from any point of the clique $K_{n-1}$ !
